# Google protocol buffers and objective C issues

Tags: objective-c, protocol-buffers

Hoping to hear from some more experienced developers (completely new to protobufs as of yesterday). I've been researching how to get protobufs to work with iOS given that Google doesn't have a homegrown library for objective C.

Experimenting a bit, it seems there are two general approaches:

1. Use a third-party library - Booyah's objective C compiler - (https://github.com/booyah/protobuf-objc).

   - The issue is that it won't compile with protobuf 2.5.0, and requires 2.4.1. Does anyone see a compelling reason NOT to use this method and use the older version of protobufs?
2. Use C++ generated protobuf classes with some tweaking - (http://www.kotancode.com/2012/10/14/using-google-protocol-buffers-in-objective-c-on-ios-and-the-mac/)

   - This doesn't seem like a very clean approach and C++ bleeding into objective-C code doesn't sound like fun.

On a related note, I can't find any documentation on cleanly uninstalling 2.5.0 if I opted for the former approach. What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: In the short term, I can not see any problem with using 2.4.1; but you probably do not want to get stuck on 2.4.1 in the long term